# VirtualBox 6.1 Using Wrong Linux Kernel Version Module Header Files

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, kernel-modules

Idk why the proper kernel mods aren't being built. I upgraded my kernel, then downgraded it. That's when VirtualBox 6.1 stopped working. To install Vbox on Mint/Ubuntu, you add their deb repo and then issue: `apt install virtualbox-6.1`. Doing this uninstalls the previous version and related packages such as:

```
virtualbox
virtualbox-dkms
```

My current kernel: **5.4.0-53-generic**

Disto: **Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia (Ubuntu 18.04)**

Upon upgrading and then downgrading the kernel (6.1 was working prior to that), I  get the following error when trying to start a VM:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

So I run `/sbin/vboxconfig` which produces:

```bsh
❯ /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
At main.c:281:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
kmodsign: /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/misc/vboxdrv.ko: No such file or directory
At main.c:281:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
kmodsign: /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/misc/vboxnetflt.ko: No such file or directory
At main.c:281:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
kmodsign: /lib/modules/5.4.0-53-generic/misc/vboxnetadp.ko: No such file or directory
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

So I try to see what it wants. There's nothing in dmesg.

```bsh
❯ locate /lib/modules/5.4.65
/lib/modules/5.4.65
/lib/modules/5.4.65/misc
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.alias
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.alias.bin
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.builtin.bin
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.dep
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.dep.bin
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.devname
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.softdep
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.symbols
/lib/modules/5.4.65/modules.symbols.bin
/lib/modules/5.4.65/misc/vboxdrv.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.65/misc/vboxnetadp.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.65/misc/vboxnetflt.ko
```

It looks like it's building for the wrong kernel. I've tried every solution I could find. No amount of rebooting or purging packages has helped so far.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Brian Turek's answer above I managed to fix the issue. I still don't know what causes this kind of issue, but reinstalling the kernel headers did not fix the problem for me. In fact I can see the issue resists for me for multiple kernel versions now.

This issue may apply to you, if the output of the both commands differ:

```
root@:/# uname -r
5.4.0-60-generic

root@:/# cat /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/config/kernel.release
5.4.78
```

In this case the module built can be found under modules from the `kernel.release` file:

```
root@:/# ls /lib/modules/5.4.78/misc/vbox*
/lib/modules/5.4.78/misc/vboxdrv.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.78/misc/vboxnetadp.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.78/misc/vboxnetflt.ko
```

When you move the modules to correct location of your currently used kernel, you can afterwards load them:

```
root@:/# mv /lib/modules/5.4.78/misc /lib/modules/5.4.0-60-generic/misc
root@:/# depmod -a
root@:/# modprobe vboxdrv
```

This is of course only a temporary workaround until you install the next version of the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19723

It looks like the kernel headers de-synced from your current kernel (it's just a managed symlink).  It looks like the easiest solution is to reinstall the specific kernel header version that matches your running kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I did experienced a similar issue.

In my case :

```
root@:/# uname -r
5.4.0-81-generic

root@:/# cat /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/config/kernel.release
5.4.128
```

No luck in reinstalling the linux-headers package. I edited and changed the value of `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/config/kernel.release` from `5.4.128` to `5.4.0-81-generic` and `vboxconfig` ran successfully and then virtualbox as well.